# SP2013 sitemap.xml of public facing website is not generated

Tags: public-website, seo

I have a public facing website, but the sitemap.xml is not generated.
The Search Engine Sitemap site collection Feature is active and I can edit the Search Engine Sitemap Settings. 
The robots.txt is automatically updated but the sitemap XML location is not appendend and the sitemap.xml is not available at http://[url]/sitemap.xml.

Do you have any suggestion what the problem might be?

Comment: How many pages do you have? If there are too may this generation will fail (search query limit, and timeouts may occur)

Comment: about 100 pages, the timer job executes without any errors

Comment: are you sure about sitemap xml path, in my case it was like http://[url]/sitemap0.xml.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually not an error but a result of an improperly configured search engine. The "Search Engine Sitemap" feature solely relies on your internal search engine to generate the sitemap.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem.
Checking Central Admin > Monitoring > Review job definitions and selecting the "Search Engine Sitemap job" showed it to be set for a daily Execution. Running this job manually seemed to execute with no errors as evident while running this [handy ULS log viewer](http://sharepointlogviewer.codeplex.com/) in live monitoring mode.

My colleague found that in fact none of the jobs were being executed correctly because the Sharepoint Timer Service wasn't started. Setting it with a correct admin user and starting the service resolved the issue.

Answer (score -1):

In SharePoint Administration run
Search Engine Sitemap job Manually

Comment: Please add more details about how to do this